# Getting KeyError: "None of [Index([ ]" error when using .between_time() to average a years worth of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying create an average day from a year's worth of data. I want the average to be by user-defined time intervals. For example, if the user inputs 60 minute intervals, each day of the year will be split up into 1 hours intervals all the data from 0:00 - 1:00 will be averaged together then 1:00 to 2:00 etc. I created code for doing that, but I am having trouble with the df.between_time() method. No matter what I try I get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [78], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 time_sep_label(l2_power)

Input In [77], in time_sep_label(df, time_column, resample_rate)
     18 print(int_index[0])
     19 for j in range(len(int_index)):
---> 20     df.loc[int_index[j], 'time_interval_label'] = j
     21 return(df)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:712, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    710 else:
    711     key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 712 indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
    713 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
    715 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:661, in _LocationIndexer._get_setitem_indexer(self, key)
    659 if isinstance(key, tuple):
    660     with suppress(IndexingError):
--> 661         return self._convert_tuple(key)
    663 if isinstance(key, range):
    664     return list(key)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:799, in _LocationIndexer._convert_tuple(self, key)
    797     self._validate_key_length(key)
    798     for i, k in enumerate(key):
--> 799         idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i)
    800         keyidx.append(idx)
    802 return tuple(keyidx)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1291, in _LocIndexer._convert_to_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1289         return inds
   1290     else:
-> 1291         return self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)[1]
   1292 else:
   1293     try:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1327, in _LocIndexer._get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1324 ax = self.obj._get_axis(axis)
   1325 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1327 keyarr, indexer = ax._get_indexer_strict(key, axis_name)
   1329 return keyarr, indexer

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5782, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   5779 else:
   5780     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 5782 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   5784 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
   5785 if isinstance(key, Index):
   5786     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5842, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   5840     if use_interval_msg:
   5841         key = list(key)
-> 5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5844 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
   5845 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "None of [Index([                                                            ('s', 'h', 'a', 'r', 'k', 'i', 'd'),\n                                                                             ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e'),\n       ('t', 'i', 'm', 'e', '_', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'v', 'a', 'l', '_', 'l', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l')],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

I checked and do not have spaces in the column names. I am not sure why it is outputting that error. Thank you for the help.

My code: (Note: I am calling the time_sep_label() function I have not found the average yet get_avg_day())

```
def day_time(freq = '1min'):
    # Create the number on intervals during the day
    time_array = pd.date_range('0:00', '23:59:59', freq=freq).strftime('%H:%M')
    return(time_array)

def time_sep_label(df, time_column = 'time', resample_rate = '1T'):
    # Ensure time column is in datetime format
    df[time_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[time_column])
    # Set time column as index
    df = df.set_index(df[time_column])
    # Remove time column from dataframe since it is now the index
    df = df.drop(columns = [time_column])
    # Clean up and resample missing data 
    df = df.resample(resample_rate).mean()
    # Extract the time period ths user wants in a day as an integer
    resample_rate_int =  int(resample_rate.rstrip(resample_rate[-1]))
    # Change '1T' to '1min' Call the daytime function to produce the time intervals
    time_array = day_time(str(resample_rate_int) + 'min')
    # Create a new column for labeling each row 
    df['time_interval_label'] = np.nan
    # Declare the list for indexes for ever interval
    int_index = []
    # Extract the indexes for ever interval
    for i in range(len(time_array) - 1):
        int_index.append(df.between_time(time_array[i], time_array[i + 1], inclusive = 'left'))
    # Create the time column in the dateframe again
    df.insert(loc=0, column=time_column, value=df.index)
    # Reset the index 
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    # Label the index for every interval
    for j in range(len(int_index)):
        df.loc[int_index[j], 'time_interval_label'] = j
    return[df, time_array]
def get_avg_day(df, time_column = 'time', resample_rate = '1T', value_column =  'value'):
    # Call the time_sep_label data to get the labeled dataframe
    df, time_array = time_sep_label(df, time_array, time_column = time_column, resample_rate = resample_rate)
    # Declare the list that will contain the average values for each interval
    avg_day_array = []
    # Populate the list that will contain the average values for each interval
    for i in range(len(time_array) - 1):
        avg_day_array.append(df[value_column][df['time_interval_label'] == i].mean())  
    return(avg_day_array)
```